# How can I document links in rest doc

Tags: java, spring-boot, hateoas, spring-restdocs

I'm trying to document method which return list of owners using spring rest docs but i don't know how to document links provided by Hateoas.

linkWithRel(...) not working on _embedded.ownerDtoList object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class OwnerDto extends RepresentationModel<OwnerDto> {

@Null
private UUID id;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 3, max = 20)
private String name;

}

@GetMapping(value = "")
public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<OwnerDto>> getOwners() {
    List<OwnerDto> owners = ownerService.findAllOwners();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-Owners-Total", Integer.toString(owners.size()));
    owners.stream().map(owner -> owner
            .add(linkTo(OwnerController.class).slash(owner.getId()).withSelfRel())
            .add(linkTo(OwnerController.class).withRel("owners")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Link mainSelfLink = linkTo(OwnerController.class).withSelfRel();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            new CollectionModel<>(owners, mainSelfLink),
            headers,
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
}        



public void findAllOwners() throws Exception {

    List<OwnerDto> ownerDtoList = Arrays.asList(ownerDto_1, ownerDto_2);
    Mockito.when(ownerService.findAllOwners()).thenReturn(ownerDtoList);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/owner")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.ownerDtoList[0].id", is(ownerDto_1.getId().toString())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.ownerDtoList[0].name", is(ownerDto_1.getName())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.ownerDtoList[1].id", is(ownerDto_2.getId().toString())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.ownerDtoList[1].name", is(ownerDto_2.getName())))
            .andExpect(header().longValue("X-Owners-Total", 2L))
            .andDo(document("v1/{method-name}", ownerPageHeadersSnippet(), ownerCollectionResponseFieldsSnippet(),

                    links(
                            halLinks(),
                            linkWithRel("owners").description("Get all owners <<Resource>>"),
                            linkWithRel("self").description("Self <<Resource>>")
                    )
            ));
}

{
"_embedded": {
    "ownerDtoList": [
        {
            "id": "9eccbed8-6184-470c-b635-7d7bd4196caf",
            "name": "Szymaa",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner/9eccbed8-6184-470c-b635-7d7bd4196caf"
                },
                "owners": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "f0edf088-d1ff-49dc-9561-e65ab0dcd645",
            "name": "dsad23",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner/f0edf088-d1ff-49dc-9561-e65ab0dcd645"
                },
                "owners": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner"
    }
}
```

}

> org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Links with the following relations were not found in the response: [owners]

Answer (score 0):

Spring REST Docs doesn't support this out of the box. Rather than documenting the links for the embedded resource as part of the documentation for each resource that embeds it, the recommended approach is to link to the documentation for the embedded resource instead. In your case, that would be a link to the documentation for the `ownerDtoList` resource (which I suspect is available as http://localhost:8088/api/v1/owner).

If you'd prefer to document the embedded resource links everywhere that they are embedded, you can implement a custom `LinkExtractor` and use it in place of `halLinks()`.

You can learn a bit more about the above in [this Spring REST Docs issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/381).